# Arrays and enhanced for loops?

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone please explain what is going on in this method?

```
class test{  
public static void main(String args[])
{
   int[] x = new int[4]; 
   int[] xy = new int[4]; 
  //System.out.println(xy[0]); 
    for(int j : x) { 
       xy[j] += 1;
    }
   System.out.println(xy[0]); }}
```

So I thought that the enhanced for loop would be doing this

```
/**for(int j=0; j < x.length(); j++)
xy[j=0] = 1
xy[j=1]=1
xy[j=2]=1
xy[j=3]=1*/
```

but from what I've been reading, the enhanced for loop is doing `for(int element:array)`. Still, I don't understand what the for loop in my method is actually doing. I have tried `System.out.println()` statements to check what was being put into the array `xy`, but it is either addresses or 0.

Thanks for all the help and apologizes if this is confusing.

Comment: Do you want the program according to what you "THOUGHT"       ?                                                                                                                                                                                                           ?

Answer (score 3):

For Each loop that you have used in here does assign j a value that is already assigned to array x (which in your case is 0 ).

As according to your case of x and xy array:-

```
x[0]=0;    xy[0]=0
x[1]=0;    xy[0]=0
x[2]=0;    xy[0]=0
x[3]=0;    xy[0]=0
```

Describing for each loop according to your program case:-

```
for(j : x)
```

1. This implies it will run for 4 times which is the length of your array x.
2. when running first time the following process will happen

   ```
   j=x[0] (so j=0 coz x[0] according to your case)
   xy[0]=xy[0]+1 (so now xy[0] value becomes 1)
   ```
3. Similarly 
   for the second run of for each

   ```
   j=x[1] (so j=0 coz x[0] according to your case)
   xy[0]=xy[0]+1 (so now xy[0] value becomes 2 as in previous for each run xy[0]=1)
   ```
4. So all in all finally you will have `xy[0]=4` at the end of 4th run of for each loop.

Finally the print statement will print 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] x = new int[4];
```

This creates an array of 4 elements. Each element's value is 0.

```
for(int j : x) { 
   xy[j] += 1;
}
```

This iterates through all the values of `x`. At each iteration, `j` is the next element in `x`, but since all elements are initialized to 0, j is always 0. So, the 4 iterations increment `xy[0]`.

Comment: is this usual? cuz I never saw such thing and what is goal of such for loop?

Comment: @KickButtowski the behaviour and general use of the foreach loop is normal. The kind of array (all zeros) and content of the loop (incrementing the 0th element n times) are ... well ... special. Look like they come from some kind of test.

Comment: The goal is to do something with each element of an array or collection, which is, most of the time, what you want to do with a loop: `for (Employee e : employees) { increaseSalary(e); }` for example.

Comment: @JBNizet  k cool something very new and interesting. can you be kind and break it down a little more plz?

Answer (score 1):

Here in the advanced for loop, the int j does not represent the index. Rather it represents the values in the xy[] array. It is not possible to get the index of advanced for loop. If you want index, then you might have to use ordinary for loop.
Ex. If you have

```
xy[]={5,8,3,4};
for(int j:xy)
{
    println(j);
}
```

then the output would be

```
5
8
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be straight-forward to find out, if you trace through using debugger.

In brief, it is getting each value in `x`, and use the value as index to increment corresponding value in `xy`.

It will be more obvious if you initialize both array with meaningful values:

```
int[] x = {1,1,3,3}
int[] xy = new int[4]; // initialized to 0 by default
```

after your piece of code, you will find `xy` containing `{0,2,0,2}`.

---

You should understand how enhanced-for-loop is expanded for array:

```
for (T v : arr) {
    // do something 
}
```

is transformed to

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    T v = arr[i];
    // do something 
}
```

Obviously your understanding on how enhanced for loop being expanded is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need only for-loop and not enhanced for-loop:

```
for(int j = 0 ; x.length > j; j ++) { 
   xy[j] += 1;
}
```

Problem with your code is that your loop traverse only at index 0 of xy hence you get xy as [4, 0, 0, 0]

```
int[] x = new int[4];//default values [0, 0, 0, 0]
int[] xy = new int[4]; //default values [0, 0, 0, 0]
for(int j : x) { // j is always 0
   xy[j] += 1;// xy[0] += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  for-loop instead:

```
for(int i = 0 ; x.length > i; i ++) { 
xy[i] += 1;
}
```

If you want to still use for each then here is the example

```
a[]={1,2,3,4};
for(int i:a)
{
println(i);
}
```

Hope it helps!